# How can I include multi-select parameters in my SSRS report?

Tags: sql, select, reporting-services, parameters

I have an SSRS report with a multi-select parameter.

I want to include the parameter in my data-set. The data-set is made using a SQL query. Usually, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = @parameter
```

How would I achieve the exact same outcome, using a multi select parameter?

E.G. the parameter could have the following options ticked:

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 3

So my query should work like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value in ('Option 1', 'Option 2' 'Option 3')
```

So, with a parameter, i'd imaging it would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value in (@parameter)
```

But what would the correct syntax be to refer to the multi-select report parameter using my dataset built from an SQL query?

Comment: There are hundred of tutorials and walk through on how to do exactly this! A google search will show you how

Comment: Are you saying you want something like this `SELECT *, @parameter FROM table WHERE value in (@parameter)` I know that doesn't work - just trying to understand exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you query is directly in the report's dataset (so NOT a stored procedure) then your final SELECT would work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE value in (@parameter)
```

SSRS will convert the values into a comma separated list and inject them into your script so you don't need to do anything.

Answer (score -1):

on SSRS 2016 I can use

```
= any(string_to_array(@parameter, ','))
```

also make sure to allow for multiple values

[image]